# Find the distance between two parallel side of a rhombus

Tags: geometry

At first sight, this problem seems pretty straight forward, but I can't get an easy answer for it. Can anyone help me on this? Thank you in advance!

The area of a rhombus is 32 √ 2 and its perimeter is 32. Find the distance between two parallel sides.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Perimeter is 32 means each side is 8.

The area of a rhombus is side * h

Where height h is the distance between the side you're considering and the opposite side ( here it happens to be what you want to calculate ! )

So now you now that :

```
8 * h = 32 * sqrt(2)
```

Which leads to :

```
h = 4 * sqrt ( 2 )
```

Useless Edit : YEAH my first validated answer =)

Answer (score 1):

If $CA=2a,BD=2b$ unit and $O$ is midpoint of $CA,BD$

$\dfrac122a\cdot2b=32\sqrt2$

$CD^2=DO^2+OD^2=a^2+b^2$ and $4CD=32$

Can you take it from here?